# how to show the hidden div with same properties css with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

how to show the hidden div (info-alimento1) with  same properties css with jquery, because with .show() , not working,changes the position

http://jsfiddle.net/acuario1220/kegctsnv/2/

```
$("#alimento1").mouseenter(function() {
            $( "#alimento2" ).fadeTo( "slow", 0.40 );
            $( "#info-alimento1" ).show();
        });
        $("#alimento1").mouseleave(function() {
            $( "#alimento2" ).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );



        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.show()` will set your element to be `display: block;` instead of `display: inline-block;` as you intend.. so to do this, you can instead do `.css({display: 'inline-block'});`

Answer (score 0):

The show() function will change an element's 'display' property to 'block' and this is over-riding your 'display: inline-block' rule.

You should change your JavaScript to this: (notice I changed `.show();` to `.css('display', 'inline-block');`)

```
$("#alimento1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#alimento2").fadeTo("slow", 0.40);
    $("#info-alimento1").css('display', 'inline-block');
});
$("#alimento1").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#alimento2").fadeTo("slow", 1);
});
```

You also have conflicted CSS, which is never a good idea. You should consider removing the `display: inline-block;` rule from your css. This will leave you with the following rule:

```
#info-alimento1 {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 2px solid #cfd9ea;
    margin-top: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left: -80px;
    display: none;
}
```